# Logic gate without transistor

Tags: logic-gates

I wonder how to make logic gates without transistors, logic-integrated circuits, or diodes. The components that I need are: two terminal push switches, a resistor, a 3v battery, led.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  There are any number of "intro to digital logic" guides that use switch logic as an example.

Comment: No. I was fiddling around with a breadboard and was wondering if it is possible to make logic gates without using transistors.

Comment: Two or more switches in series performs "AND" function, two or more switches in parallel performs "OR" function. Unfortunately, there's no way to do "NOT" directly, so it isn't a "universal" system of logic.

Comment: You can use relays and other electromechanicals and have a 5 horsepower computer: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Mark_I

Comment: @DaveTweed what about a NC switch?

Comment: @jsotola Look up ["Porter's relay computer" on the web](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the resistor in series with the LED. Put two switches in series and you will get an AND gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fardWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Put them in parallel to get an OR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6gop.png)</sup>

Put one switch like in the circuit drawn below for a NOT gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffYHO6.png)</sup>

Comment: Yes, but the "NOT gate" is not in a form that can be combined easily with the "AND" and "OR" configurations to create arbitrarily complex logic.

Comment: @DaveTweed Dude asks about making a logic gate (singular) without transistors and diodes, not about creating "arbitrarily complex logic".

Comment: Is it possible to make a xor gate using and,or,not gates?